# Computer wont boot to windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, partitioning, backtrack

I recently installed a Linux operating  system (backtrack 5 r3) I couldn't connect to the internet with it so I removed the partition manually. After that, whenever I turn on my computer it goes to a command line that says "error no File-system found" "Grub Rescue/"

I have tried f12 and booted into all the options. I also put Ubuntu 12.04 on my flash drive and tried installing it on the computer, the installation failed saying "No Available Space"

My hard-drive is 500g with about 250 left. I put the hard drive in another computer (as a secondary just to see the files. It had 2 partitions a main and one with 1 gig. I formatted it with no difference.

My Problem: I can't boot into Windows

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

- Boot with your Windows CD/DVD and use the repair option.
- Boot with Plop boot manager / Super grub CD / Parted Magic, that kind of Boot CDs will find your Windows partition and boot it

Comment: I tried booting from a recovery disk, It did not recognize it as a bootable disk. I tried 2 different recovery disks. I will Try the command, How do i find my partition number? is it 1 by defualt?

Comment: Commands not recognized.

Comment: sorry, the Grub option is not possible in rescue mode, edited it

Comment: I have access to the hard drives files (taking out hard drive and putting it in another) Can i fix it from there? Is there a file that i can delete / edit that decides how it boots?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you can reinstall a bootloader (Grub or any other one) on the MBR of the disk, but the boot-cd option is better

Comment: I tried booting from a recovery disk. It did not recognize it as a boot disk.

Comment: How do i "reinstall a bootloader on the MBR of the disk" (I want win7 back)

Comment: Could you give me a link for a tutorial? I couldnt find one on google.

Comment: @JacobEggebeen: Do you have a Win7 Setup DVD? Try [that](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) and use the automated startup repair or use `bootrec` [from the command prompt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392).

Comment: I do not have the disk.

Comment: The Computer keeps booting to a 1 gig partition

Comment: I plugged the drive on another commuter. i saw there was 5 partitions, I deleted 3 of them and it deleted my main drive. I NEED to get the data back.

Comment: @JacobEggebeen: "I do not have the disk" - I linked to the ISO in my previous comment. Did you see that? (BTW, don't forget to use `@name` when responding to someone or they don't get notified.)