# Need copyied hard drive to be bootable

Tags: mbr

I copied all the contents of a hard drive to another. It wont boot of it though. I need it to.
I deleted a partition and used a data recovery, The files i copied were the recovered ones. It recovered EVERY file.

Comment: How do you know that it recovered every file, and that the contents of every file are correct?

Comment: Did you try the things mentioned in your previous post? http://superuser.com/questions/616963/computer-wont-boot-to-windows

Comment: If you copied *all* of the content on the old drive to the new, the computer would boot off the new as it did off the old. I take it you want some help with getting the computer to boot from the new drive, but right now there is nothing for us to go on in diagnosing this problem. Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/619162/edit) and describe *how* you copied the files, what the state of the new drive is now, and what error messages (if any) you are receiving and at what point. Right now, I'd say this question is unanswerable; strictly speaking, it isn't even a question.

Comment: Did you **copy *or* clone** your drive?  The two are very different...

Comment: @nerdwaller copy

Comment: @dtmland yes i did

Comment: @DarthAndroid i had a saved dir txt file.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling In device manager it says it does not say it is bootable

Comment: So just to be clear, you have the original hard drive around still, but have deleted partitions on it already?

Comment: on the orignal one, ALL it has is the windows partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find (possibly among other problems) that it did not reinstall the boot sector, which is not a file, but the bit at the very beginning of the disk which tells the system how to boot.   You will, at minimum, need to restore the boot loader (ie MBR).    You did not advise an OS, so its difficult to provide more accurate information, but you should be able to Google "install bootloader [OS]" in Google to get the answer on how to do this for your OS.

Comment: The OP mentioning Device Manager and a Windows partition in comments points pretty strongly toward an NT-based version of Windows.